# In what case would stripe's transfer.failed webhook be sent?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm working with stripe connect, creating separate charges and transfers for my business. I'm trying to write code to notify my support team of the event when a transfer fails, so that they can intervene. My problem is that I can't get any transfers to fail in the test environment. Creating a transfer for more money than is in my test account doesn't trigger the transfer.failed webhook, it just returns an error. In the dashboard > developers > webhooks, there is the feature to send a test webhook of any type to a webhook endpoint, but I'm using the stripe cli on my computer.

What are the different events that can trigger a transfer.failed webhook?

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) as they'd have the ability to give you an exact list of when this event would fire based on your API version and anything else involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test using an external bank account that refuses payment - the response should not be instant, but delayed a bit

ex: `DE89370400440532013002 Payout fails with an account_closed code.` (remember to change DE from the iban to wherever you are)

Another way could be to create a stripe account that is not verified and try to make a large transfer to it. (like >5000$ in test mode)